# Difference between the Cortana skills created from store vs cortana dev centre

Tags: azure, bots, azure-cognitive-services, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I created 2 sample bot application from azure portal, and added 1 skill directly from [cortana Dev centre](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana) and another skill from [store](https://my.knowledge.store/).

Now if i login to store, i can see my skills having different properties are there and there is a difference in ?URL

Skill 1: https://my.knowledge.store/workspace/mathilearnings/**botframework**/mathilearnings.mybot1/overview

skill 2: https://my.knowledge.store/workspace/mathilearnings/**botlet**/mathilearnings.mybot2/overview.

Please suggest what is the right way to create the skills, and what is the difference between these 2 different approach.